# Firestore - How to perform "NOT IN" like you would in SQL

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of "quizes" that users will participate in. When a user takes a quiz I create a document in "results" collection for with that userId and quizId. I want my app to pull all docs from "quizes" collection excluding the ones that the user taken. In SQL I would do "NOT IN" clause and accomplish that, but I have no idea how to best approach this in Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent query in Firestore. You would need to pull all the data and determine which docs are relevant on clientside.

Alternatively, you can create a list of all quizzes for each user and maintain this list. You could add and remove quizzes for each user as they become relevant/irrelevant to show them.

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying that best practice in this case is - I have to make another request to get all "results" for that user and cross match it with "quizes" clientside to determine what to show the user?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's considered a best practice, but that's one way of going about it. I've seen mixed opinions on maintaining feeds vs. pulling all data. My concerns with pulling all data are around consumption. That's a lot of reads and, personally, I would prefer to use some writes to maintain the user's lists. Since my app is otherwise fairly low on writes, they would otherwise go to waste on the Flame plan.